# BPS service not starting at the launch of the app Blackberry10

Tags: c++, blackberry-10

```
   if(bps_initialize() == BPS_SUCCESS){
      qDebug() << "............................................"; 
      netstatus_interface_details_t *details;
      if (netstatus_get_interface_details(interface, &details) == BPS_SUCCESS) {
           QString ipAddr = netstatus_interface_get_ip_address(details, 0);
          netstatus_free_interface_details(&details);
      }
   }
bps_shutdown();
```

I am calling this function at the launch of my app to get the ip address of the device. But ( netstatus_get_interface_details(interface, &details) ) is returning false and the application crashes when i am removing this if statement. What might be the reason. Any help? this code is working perfectly fine if I am calling this function in my app at any time apart from when i am launching the app.... Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't show that "interface" is set to. It must be an interface returned by netstatus_get_interfaces(), netstatus_info_get_default_interface() or NULL.